# Passport in node.js

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Ok, I edit the question, Can someone help me with fix this code, to work??

I am fallow the guide with youtube about creating login system with using passport, I dont understand here about function

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
```

When is she called, And from where it gets an argument login, password.

USER MODEL

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


    var UserSchema = new Schema({
      login: { type: String, maxlength: 20, required: false },
      password: { type: String, maxlength: 202, required: false },
      updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
      created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }

    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

    module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
        bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
            if(err) throw err;
            callback(null, isMatch);
        });
    }

    module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
        User.findById(id, callback);
    }
```

User Model

```
var express = require('express');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var Product = require('../../model/product.model');
var Category = require('../../model/category.model');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('../../model/user.model');
var _ = require('lodash');

var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;




router.post('/create', function (req, res, next) {

  var newUser = {
    login: req.body.login,
    password: req.body.password
  }
  console.log(req.body)

  req.checkBody('login', 'Login is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();

  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    console.log(errors)
    res.send(errors);
  } else {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, saltRounds, function (err, hash) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      } else {
        newUser.password = hash;
        var user = new User(newUser);
        user.save()
          .then(function (User) {
            res.send(User);
          })
      }
    });
    req.flash('success_msg', 'You are registered and can now login');

    //res.redirect('/');
  }
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(login, password, done) {
  User.findOne({ login: login }, function(err, user){
    if(err) { 
      console.log(err); 
    }
    if(!user) {
      return done(null, false, {
        message: 'Unkown User'
      })
    }
  });


  User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(isMatch){
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
        }
    });
  }));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});


router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body)
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/', failureFlash: true }),
    function (req, res) {
      res.redirect('/product/list')
    }
})



module.exports = router;
```

Comment: If there is something in particular that you do not understand in the [docs](http://passportjs.org/docs), you should state that explicitly. We won't be making guesses.

Comment: I can not understand main utilization this thing, I am trying to do login system with Passport but, I don't understand what is he doing there what he have for the task, please explain me only this thing why i must use this passport

Comment: Again, no, we won't make a broad, tailored explanation to suit your needs, because we really cannot do that. Even your comment adds no further detail on what you are working on or attempting to do. If you do not even understand the part that "Passport is authentication middleware for Node.js", you will need much more than a question here. Consider doing further learning and research, or seek help in other websites.

Comment: I updated If u could, try help me

Answer (score 0):

**When is she called?**

`passport.use(new LocalStrategy(` will be used when you call `passport.authenticate('local'..`
In your project it is while getting post request with `'/login'`.

LocalStrategy provides strategy to authenticate requests. You can choose different strategy. Strategies, and their configuration, are supplied via the `use()` function.  More information: [Passport Documentation](http://passportjs.org/docs/configure)

**From where it gets an argument login, password?**

By default, LocalStrategy expects to find credentials in parameters named username and password. If your site prefers to name these fields differently, options are available to change the defaults.
From [LocalStrategy Documentataion](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local)